# ui-select only work in first tab in tabset

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ui-select2

Code here

```html
        <tabset justified="true">

            <tab heading="tab1"  select="switchTier1Tab('qe')">
                    tab1content
            </tab>

            <tab  heading="tab2" select="switchTab('default')">
                <ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleResult.selectedRecordsWithGroupBy" theme="select2"  on-select="modelselected($item, $model)" style="width: 100%" >
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="search records here...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices  group-by="'group'" repeat="record in records | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}">
                        <span ng-bind-html="record.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                    </ui-select-choices>
                </ui-select>
            </tab>
            <tab heading="xx">
                tabcontent3
            </tab>
        </tabset>
```

when I put the ui-select in the first tab ,it works ,but when i put it in the second tab .the ui-select does not work ,I can see not data.Can any one help explain this?

Answer (score 0):

can you check if the width is set as 0px, which is why you are unable to get the input type text for the ui-select.
The issue with ui-select is that width of the text box is being calculated from the container. So when the select box is in the 2nd tab the width of the input type is set as 0px.

Lemme know if this helps you out